# Simple Navigation Button - WIndowScrollBy Coordinates from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, scroll, navigation

I would like to have a fixed-position button that would make the page scroll to different positions. These positions would come from an array.

I have tried this but I simply cannot get it to work. Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong or even better show me a working example? Thanks!

```js
<script>

var hor = ['300','300','300'];
var ver = ['300','300','300'];

for (i = 0; i < hor.length; i++) {hor[i];}

for (i = 0; i < ver.length; i++) {ver[i];}

function scrollWin(){window.scrollBy(hor[i], ver[i]);}

</script>
```

```html
<html>
<body style="width: 20000px; height:20000px;">

<button style="display: block; cursor: pointer; position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 10px; width: 200px; height: 50px; border: 2px solid blue; color: white; background-color: #4090ee;" onclick="scrollWin();"/>Scroll
</button>

<div style="position: absolute; top:400px; left:400px;width:400px;height:400px;background-color:orange;">
REFERENCE
</div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the for loops are supposed to do.  Are you trying to run them all in succession?  I have modified your code to scroll by 300 each time they click the button.

```js
var hor = ['300','300','300'];
var ver = ['300','300','300'];

var i = 0;

function scrollWin(){
  var s = i % 3;
  window.scrollBy(hor[s], ver[s]);
  i++;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body style="width: 20000px; height:20000px;">

<button style="display: block; cursor: pointer; position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 10px; width: 200px; height: 50px; border: 2px solid blue; color: white; background-color: #4090ee;" onclick="scrollWin();"/>Scroll
</button>

<div style="position: absolute; top:400px; left:400px;width:400px;height:400px;background-color:orange;">
REFERENCE
</div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it seems it is working just as I wanted it to - The loop was for the scroll to begin anew from the last array position.  The idea is to have just one button in a fixed screen position, which will take the user across pages of different heights and widths, in a navigation experience both vertical and horizontal, and which will loop back to the beginning in the end, in a non-ending circle. I will test your solution but I think you solved it, thanks a lot! I just do not understand what is the % 3 in your code, could you enlighten me about that?

Comment: The '%' is the modulo operator.  It takes the remainder of the operation, which gives you the loop you wanted.  Meaning if i = 4, i % 3 = 1.  I.E.  4 / 3 has a remainder of 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder

Comment: Oh, I forgot to ask one thing: Would it be possible to make the scroll smooth? (I have read about "slow" option for scrolling, but I would not know where to insert it...sorry to trouble you, but I am a beginner, and what you have done in a few minutes I had been trying for 2 days...it´s not easy to become proficient at this....).

Comment: I am trying to thank you by commending you or voting for you but couldn´t find where to do it...either this site´s interface should be simpler or I should be smarter...and I am afraid it´s the latter....rsrs.

Comment: @humblebeginner It is definitely possible to make the scrolling smooth, but it is not super simple.  I would suggest using jQuery.  jQuery has an animate function that will let you animate the scrolling.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: @humblebeginner As far as accepting this as the answer, there should be a button on the left side by my answer that allows you to accept it.